# Drawing a diamond triangle graph in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf

I' was having mathematics (graph theory) class and my teacher asked us to draw this picture using LaTeX. I totally have no idea to start with. I really need your helps and please enclose the step by step how to create them. 
[image: Pic 1]

and

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your previous questions, you had MWEs. What made you lose the ability to provide them.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) node[bullet,label=below:$v_1$] (v1){} 
 -- (45:1) node[bullet,label=45:$v_2$] (v2){}
 -- (80:1) node[bullet,label=80:$v_3$] (v3) {}
 -- (v1) -- (0:1) node[bullet,label=right:$v_4$] (v4) {}
 -- (-35:1) node[bullet,label=-35:$v_5$] (v5) {} -- (v1);
\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
 \draw (0,0) node[bullet,label=below:$v_1$] (v1'){} 
 -- (100:1) node[bullet,label=100:$v_2$] (v2'){}
 -- (65:1) node[bullet,label=65:$v_3$] (v3') {}
 -- (30:1) node[bullet,label=right:$v_4$] (v4') {}
 -- (-5:1) node[bullet,label=-5:$v_5$] (v5') {} -- (v1')
 -- (v3')  (v1') -- (v4');
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,scale=pi/2]
 \edef\lstX{{"","1","2","3","4","n-2","n-1","n"}}
 \foreach \X [remember=\X as \LastX] in {7,...,1} 
 {\foreach \Y [remember=\Y as \LastY]in {7,...,\X}
  {\pgfmathsetmacro{\myX}{\lstX[\X]}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\myY}{\lstX[8-\Y]}
  \ifnum\Y=5
   \node[bullet] (v-\X-\Y) at ($\X*(120:1)+\Y*(1,0)$){};
  \else
   \node[bullet,label=45:$v_{\myX\myY}$] (v-\X-\Y) at ($\X*(120:1)+\Y*(1,0)$){};
  \fi
  \ifnum\Y=7
   \ifnum\X=7
   \else
    \draw (v-\X-\Y)  -- (v-\LastX-\Y);
   \fi  
  \else
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tstY}{int(abs(4.5-\Y))}
   \ifnum\tstY=0
    \draw[dashed] (v-\X-\LastY) -- (v-\X-\Y) -- (v-\LastX-\LastY);
   \else    
    \draw (v-\X-\LastY) -- (v-\X-\Y) -- (v-\LastX-\LastY);
   \fi
  \fi
  }}
  \node[bullet,below=2cm of v-1-4] (v0){};
  \foreach \X in {1,...,7} 
   {\ifnum\X=5
    \draw[dashed] (v0) -- (v-1-\X);
   \else
    \draw (v0) -- (v-1-\X);
   \fi}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for reminding me to give a green check for those people who had answered my previous question. By the way, I have no idea how to build these complicated (for me) picture. Do you have any suggestion where should I learn about drawing mathematics picture like these?.